# Editing Folder content in tomcat manually?

Tags: java, html, apache, tomcat, war

I have a WAR file called `ROOT.war` where I uploaded into `Tomcat` few days back. There I have few "public" HTML pages like index.html, about.html etc. These pages has no connection with the programatic part of the application, instead containing  a link for `login.jsp`.

Now, I need to change the content of the `index.html` and `about.html`. What I was used to do is rebuild the entire WAR file and re-uplaod it, but now can't do it for small and iterative changes like this because the application is in use.

So, can I simply access the `webapps -> ROOT` folder in `Tomcat` and replace the index.html? Will it affect the process of the application?

Comment: Did you try? Sure you can, but a redeploy of that war file (i.e. server restart, having "unpack-wars" attribute set to true) will overwrite those changes. An Html file is static and will not affect the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and It will work. You can even change the JSP code. The only issue you may have is that when you redeploy a new version of the war, changes made in the server will ve overriden by the new version, so you better change it in the original tool also.

Comment: A miss can make things lost for forever.

Comment: Yes, I change them in the original tool as well.

Comment: As it has been noted it is not the recommended way of doing code updates, but it will work. Ïf the problem is with repetitive changes, maybe the solution is to feed the app with a DB or a content file located in a known location.

Answer (score 2):

It works but avoid such practices which lead to discrepancies.

Follow standard deployment process - rebuild the entire WAR file and re-upload it during deployment window.

Comment: Re-deployments are not possible as the users using it will lose all the transactions during the redeployment time.

Comment: Re-upload it during deployment window. Choose what fits best.